# How to decide the H cost in A* Search Algorithm for cities connected with roads

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

How to decide `heuristic cost` for the `cities connected with roads` problem. The graph has non negative weighted unidirectional edges and no edge connects any vertex to itself. In this graph, there is only one edge between any two vertices. My aim is to get the shortest distance between `single source` and `single destination`.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to be a little more explicit. Can you describe your problem a little more clearly, please?

Comment: How to calculate the `h` cost for a weighted unidirectional graph, which has non negative edge weight. for example: `cities connected with roads problem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your edges lie in a Euclidian plane, your vertices correspond to roads, and the vertex cost is the length of the road, then the [Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or L2 norm is a good choice for the heuristic cost.

---

Here's why. But first, some quick terminology:

Let `f(x)` be the **path cost**, the calculated shortest distance from the start node to node `x`.

Let `h(x)` be the **heuristic cost**, an estimate of the distance to the goal from node `x`.

Because [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) is a **directed best-first** search algorithm. At each step it moves to the node which minimizes  `h(x) + f(x)` (and calculating `h(x)` requires that we have a goal node in mind).

---

For this approach to be **guaranteed** to find the correct shortest patch distance between the start and end nodes, `h(x)` must be an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic). This essentially means that **it must not overestimate the distance to the goal node**.

Therefore, if your nodes are organized on a Euclidian plane, and your costs correspond to the L2 norm distance between the nodes, then the [Euclidian distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or L2 norm between the current node `x` and the goal node is guaranteed to be an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) (it's the shortest possible path between the two nodes, so any actual path along a series of vertices in your graph must be longer).

---

As a bonus, it's informative to note that [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is simply a special case of [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) with `h(x) = 0`. For any node, we assume that the path to the goal is `0`, which means we simply take the smallest possible step. This is certainly an [admissible heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) because the distance between any two nodes cannot be less than `0` (if we're assuming non-negative edge costs).

Comment: To calculate `Euclidian distance` one should know coordinates of nodes. But in my graph, cities are connected with roads, i only know the length of roads. and in my graph no edge connects any vertex to itself. Also, there is only one road between any two cities. So how can i calculate `Euclidean distance`?

Comment: Hmmm... In that case the best you may be able to do is set h(x)=0 and reduce the problem to Dijkstra's algorithm. It will be slower but you'll be guarenteed to find the correct shortest path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to optimize for distance travelled, euclidean distance is a good baseline heuristic.

Comment: i am trying to get the shortest distance from `single source` to `single destination`. Will `euclidean distance` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're given a weighted graph, use the edge weight as if it's the length of the segment.  The shortest path in a weighted graph is the path with the lowest combined edge weight.